# Extract part of string using C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to extract a part of a string in C#, but am not sure how to accomplish this. I imagine Regex, but being a complete RegEx noob I figured I would ask the community for some help.

I have a string much like the one below:

```
Unit Code : Billing Period : Billing Date : Due Date : Total Amount Due : STATEMENT OF ACCOUNT Page No.: Page 1 of 2 July 2016 1S-D-0303 07/07/2016 JOHN DOE Unit 303D, Building name, CITY NAME
```

I am looking to extract the number "2" from the "Page 1 of 2" statement, as well as the "1S-D-0303" and "07/07/2016" part.

I try hope someone out there can help, as I am pretty much stuck and Googling hasn't gotten me anywhere.

Comment: What you have tried ???

Comment: As per my statement above, nothing in terms of RegEx as I don't know how to use it.

Comment: are you sure `1S-D-0303` will be of same pattern.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: Are you really saying that https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Extract+part+of+string+using+C%23 didn't help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code matches exactly the 3 parts you are looking for:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string pattern = @"Page [0-9]+ of ([0-9]+) [A-Z][a-z]+ [0-9]+ ([0-9A-Za-z-]+) ([0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9]+)";

Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
MatchCollection mc = r.Matches("Unit Code : Billing Period : Billing Date : Due Date : Total Amount Due : STATEMENT OF ACCOUNT Page No.: Page 1 of 2 July 2016 1S-D-0303 07/07/2016 JOHN DOE Unit 303D, Building name, CITY NAME");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression like this ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/wG2mL3/1)):

```
Page (?<CurrentPage>\d+) of (?<TotalPage>\d+) \w+ \w+ (?<Code>.*?) (?<Date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get the first part of your request:

Page\s1\sof\s(.)

Take a look at https://regex101.com/ which provides a regex tester and some helpful hints.